# I can't open a userform from a main userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm Using Excel 2013 vba.  I have 2 Forms: frmMain and .  In frmMain, I only have a cmd button with a code UserForm1.show ,however i can't open the UserForm1.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Visible = False     'This code hides the workbook
UserForm1.Show                  'Brings the UserForm

End Sub
```

'Module1 Code..

```
Sub hidden()

Sheet1.Visible = False

End Sub
```

screenshot of my UserForm1

[image: UserForm1]

Code for UserForm1...

```
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

Private Sub cmbCalltype_Change()

'==========sayon rani dri=======

'If cmbCalltype.List(cmbCalltype.ListIndex) = "Training" Then
'    cmbGc.Enabled = False
'ElseIf cmbCalltype.List(cmbCalltype.ListIndex) = "Wrong GC" Then
'    cmbGc.Enabled = False
'ElseIf cmbCalltype.List(cmbCalltype.ListIndex) = "Wrong Number" Then
'    cmbGc.Enabled = False
'ElseIf cmbCalltype.List(cmbCalltype.ListIndex) = "Resident" Then
'    cmbGc.Enabled = False
'Else
'    cmbGc.Enabled = True
'End If

If cmbCalltype.Text = "Training" Then
    cmbGc.Enabled = False

ElseIf cmbCalltype.Text = "Resident" Then
    cmbGc.Enabled = False

ElseIf cmbCalltype.Text = "Wrong GC" Then
    cmbGc.Enabled = False

ElseIf cmbCalltype.Text = "Wrong Number" Then
    cmbGc.Enabled = False
Else
    cmbGc.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdApplicationshow_Click()

Application.Visible = True      'This will open the excel file...

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

'==========sayon rani dri=======

'Call UserForm_Initialize

txtName.Value = ""
cmbCalltype.Value = ""
cmbGc.Value = ""
cmbVisit.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdHidden_Click()

Application.Visible = False      'This will open the excel file...

End Sub

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

'Dim emptyRow As Long

'Sheet1.Activate     'Make Sheet1 active

'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
'Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtName.Value
'Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = cmbCalltype.Value
'Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = cmbVisit.Value

With Sheet1
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(txtName.Value, cmbCalltype.Value, cmbGc.Value, cmbVisit.Value)
        End With

        txtLeasing.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(2), "Leasing")      'counting the number of instances leasing text occur

        txtGc.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(3), "Yes")

        'txtYes.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(4), "Yes")
        'txtNo.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(4), "No")

        txtPercentage.Value = txtGc.Value / txtLeasing.Value * 100



        ''==================
        txtVisLeasing.Value = txtLeasing.Value
        txtTotvisit.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(4), "Yes")

        txtVisitper.Value = txtTotvisit.Value / txtVisLeasing * 100


End With

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False


txtName.Value = ""          'Empty Customer
cmbCalltype.Value = ""      'Empty Call Type
cmbGc.Value = ""            'Empty GC
cmbVisit.Value = ""         'Empty Visit

cmbCalltype.Clear
With cmbCalltype
    .AddItem "Leasing"
    .AddItem "Training"
    .AddItem "Resident"
    .AddItem "Wrong GC"
    .AddItem "Wrong Number"

End With

cmbGc.Clear
With cmbGc
    .AddItem "Yes"
    .AddItem "No"
End With

cmbVisit.Clear

With cmbVisit
   .AddItem "Yes"
   .AddItem "No"

End With
txtName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"can't open the UserForm1"*? at startup? that's the only place where you open it in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the instance of `UserForm1` called from `Workbook_Open()` same as the instance of `UserForm1` called from `frmMain` ?

- If **Yes**, then create a Module and declare the instance of `UserForm1` in `Module1` as `Public`.
- If **No**, then declare a form level instance of `UserForm1` in `frmMain`.

Something like below.

```
'frmMain Code
Dim fUser As UserForm1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  If fUser Is Nothing Then
    fUser = New UserForm1
  End If

  fUser.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mukul is it okay to send the 2 files to you..?

Comment: @DylanMecagami, ok.